# Sick Birds of Paradise

Tags: plant-care

I live in Seattle, WA and I water my birds of paradise once or twice a week depending on the weather and it has a well draining soil with drainage in the bottom.

It started getting sick inside and it started with slowed growth and yellow dots on leaves. I thought problem might be lack of sun/watering so I put it outside on the balcony where it gets 2 hours of direct morning light and many hours of indirect bright light.

I checked the roots and they seem very healthy with new bright white growth.

The new baby leaf just looks devastating with every problem you can name

I'd super appreciate it if you can help me figure out what might be going on. I checked under the leaves and I couldn't spot spider mites. [image][image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nutrient deficiencies. Firstly, take the plant off the container, plant it into a larger container or just move it into ground as that little amount of soil in your container is causing your plant to starve for nutrients. Second, add multi-micronutrient feed to plant, this includes various metals and elements that provide plants nutrient for cell growth and regeneration. Prune all the damaged leaves and add it to compost preferably near the plant, as it'll add nutrients and decaying matter with microbes to the soil and prevent further leeching of minerals by older growth/leaves. Then add a high NPK ('19-19-19'-because it's easier to find and cheap to purchase **OR** any other high balanced ration) fertilizer to plant to compensate for lost growth.

Here's how we conclude that it's a nutrient deficiency: The leaf here is of a **Banana plant & not a Bird of Paradise**, but symptoms are more or less pretty much common for all plants.
[image][image][image]

***Image courtesy/ rights reserved by science direct and the respective authors:*** [Herein, the authors attempted to create an AI application and trained it to denote common plant deficiencies](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352340923002743)